# Where does the iPhone simulator keep it's tmp/ files?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator

I'm running my iPhone app on the simulator to record my voice. It saves the recording to a .wav file, but I don't know where that is on my machine. Any help?

---

**EDIT 1**

Please keep in mind that I'm trying to 'simulate' the experience on a device. So my use of directories is crucial. See my output to the console:
[image]

---

**EDIT 2**

This is really strange. I just tried to record my voice with the Speak Here example project ('out of the box') and it worked (played back my voice and everything). Yet when I use the finder to try to locate the file... no deals! This is really bizarre. Any ideas?

Comment: @Joe Blow, Thanks, but nothing has come up. I think my answer may have to do with something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this path `/Users/<your_username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/`. In available dirs there look for `/Applications/<your_app>/Documents`.

**UPDATE (27th Jan, 2013):**

- If you're OK with Terminal, install awesome ruby gem by [Paul Samuels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632339/paul-s):
  http://paul-samuels.com/blog/2012/08/19/ios-simulator-directory-command-line-tool/.
- If you're not OK with Terminal, Paul has also created an excellent
  workflow for Alfred 2.app: http://paul-samuels.com/blog/2013/01/24/sidir-alfred-workflow/.
- If you're having hard time installing Paul's gem, follow this
  tutorial: http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac.

Comment: This seems logical, but nothing is there. I've found the iOS version folders/Applications/superLongAlpaNumericCode/myApp.app. But nothing was in the directories.

Answer (score 3):

The location of simulator files has changed in Xcode 6. It's now at:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
```

See this answer for details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24291087/2410555

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way in my experience is to output the value of [NSTemporaryDirectory()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html) somewhere in your code. That gives you the complete path to the /tmp folder for your user and application.